# Bar-code library scans irrelevant bar-code values in some cases

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using below library to scan a `barcode`

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
```

But sometimes it scans the irrelevant `barcode` values while scanning the product.

What is the need for `android:hardwareAccelerated` property on the `bar-code scanner`?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Clearly the library may be working wrong but this isn't the place to submit the bugs, the right place for that is its github page.

Comment: Don't worry there are many good library that you can use.